# How do I start a fake SMTP server automatically?

Tags: macos, email, smtp

I'm using Mac 10.9.1.  I would like to install a fake SMTP server on my system -- one that listens for emails on port 25 but doesn't actually do anything with them.  I'd like this process to start automatically upon login.  I have looked at FakeSMTP and the DevNullSMTP server, but neither seems to support an option for starting automatically (you have to launch the server manually through teh GUI).

Comment: Are you looking to learn how to make the program you selected launch (learning launchd or perhaps getting options like Launchy or Lingon) or would you instead like to ask for a software recommendation on packages that do similar and are one click install on OS X? Narrowing down your needs might get higher quality answers.

Answer (score 3):

## Login Items

You can use your account's Login Items to automatically launch an application when logging in.

- System Preferences.app > Users and Groups > Login Items

This though will only launch the application. A better solution is to find a GUI-less server and use `launchd`.

### postfix

[postfix](http://www.postfix.org/smtpd.8.html) is an open source SMTP server and it is included with Mac OS X. This is likely to be your best option for setting up a server either to do nothing but accept connections, or to become a full mail server.

### launchd

Mac OS X uses `launchd` for starting services on power on and logging in. You can learn more on the [launchd manual page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/launchd.8.html). Apple also has developer documentation for [creating launchd job tickets](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html).

To work with `launchd`, you will need an SMTP server that can be started from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason you want to run this locally? There are many web based services that provide the 'dummy' SMTP server functionality you're looking for, e.g.

[Debug Mail](https://debugmail.io)

[SMTP Bucket](http://www.smtpbucket.com)